# 486 computer does not POST

Tags: cpu, motherboard

I have some trouble trying to POST a old Intel 486 DX motherboard. If i power up the board , the CPU becomes hot quickly and it doesn't make any beep noise, but only background noise (even without RAM sticks installed).

There is one problem though : the i486 DX-33 (MHz) CPU is missing 5 pins

Here are some pictures of the motherboard and the CPU :
[image]

[image]
UPDATE: I was able to resolder the 5 missing pins and make a good electric contact (the black stuff around the pins is not electric conductive !
)

As far as i have seen, the motherboard seems perfectly fine (no missing components except the turbo LED resistor).The crystal is a 66.666 MHz one. Unfortunately, i do not have a spare 486 CPU to test.Still, even with the repaired pins, the motherboard and the CPU have the same symptoms.

The question is: Which one is "dead": the CPU  or  the motherboard ?

Comment: *Your diagram is missing or incorrectly pointing to wrong pins (i.e. they are not actually missing)*  I can also tell at least a half dozen pins are broken.  Its safe to assume that is a processor with missing pins (which are connected) and bent(which are connected) is the source of your problem.

Comment: @Ramhound Agree - Looks like S1, S2, R1, R3 and R4 are actually missing (It looks like someones had a go with a soldering iron too?).

Comment: Looks more like a hammer :$. I used the wrong word, I meant *bent* not **broken** in my earlier comment

Comment: I am sorry for the incorrect diagram,  that means a VSS rail is broken.

Comment: I am really sorry for the multiple edits i have done. My phone kept crashing while i was trying to upload images to the post. I apologize.

Comment: Why would you think a CPU with missing pins would work?

Comment: "Can I still connect or resolder the 5 missing pins somehow?" - I don't know, do you have the technical expertise to source the pins, and the soldering skills to clean and replace the pins?  Pretty good rule of thumb, if you have to ask if you can resolder something like the pins on this CPU, you likely don't have the soldering skills, in order to do so.

Comment: @ LawrenceC : A modern CPU with missing pins *might* still work. On a modern CPU a lot of the pins are power related and tie into a grid. Fewer of those pins and it might still work. But the adress and the data bus is not redundant. Any of those broken and you have no working CPU. For a 486 the same might be true if L17 was missing. (one of the ground lines bordered by two more).

Comment: Aye. Ramhound is right. While it is not technically impossible to resolver those pins it will take a lot of time and some equipment to get a good clean connection. One which is strong enough to survive re-inserting the CPU and still deliver a clean signal. In practical terms however you probbaly can not do it.

Comment: @Ramhound +1 to your comment for `If you have to ask if you can do it, you probably won't be able to do it.`; that's exactly what I answered a couple of times to similar questions. It certainly *is* possible to do so (frankly, I've once soldered transformer wires with thickness of about 0.1mm with a 100W soldering *gun*... the transformer lives to this day; done the same trick to couple SOIC ICs, all of them still working), somebody without at least a couple of years of EE experience would probably simply spill the solder everywhere, rendering the CPU completely beyond repair in the process.

Comment: I'd call the CPU trash, and even if you could do it, what's the point?  Source another machine at the local computer recyclers or from ebay and save yourself the wasted time.   Your pictured CPU is good for.... nothing now.

Comment: Actually i do have soldering skills and i have the proper equipment.But the question was focused on " does it worth it ?". Also, buying a new CPU from Ebay is not really a good option, because the shipping from U.S (where most CPUs can be found) in my area is three times or even more the price of the item.

Comment: There's a few issues here - the *length* of the pins may possibly be critical - least that's the case on many motherboard traces. "is it worth it" would depend on "why do I need a machine that's old enough to drink" and "is my time worth less than the benefit the machine would give me". Its entirely possible someone damaged the pins on the machine *post mortem* so people wouldn't try to fire it up. I used to hack off power cords on devices that were a safety hazard pre disposal so....

Comment: I remember in Winter Quarter of 2000 I took an introductory computer course, and they were using a 486DX2-66 CPU as an example of a very slow CPU that was still potentially useful (e.g., as a print server).  It was faster than the 486DX-33 I used at home.  I inquired about a swap, and was just given it.  This was over 15 years ago.  That CPU is not worth effort to try to save (w/ results possibly unreliable).  If such parts are so inefficient to get, one piece at a time, then provide a service to your neighbors (acquiring efficiently) ; It sounds like this could be a good business opportunity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your two pictures anbd the 'rounded' corner you are missing these signals:

- Data 20
- Data 22
- Data 19
- VSS (one of the power lines. It might not need this to work).
- VSS (one of the power lines. It might not need this to work).

Now less power, or less equal supplied power might not be enough to break things, but lacking three datalines is deadly. So it will simply not work without D19/20/22.

That does not mean that repairing these is enough, or that it will work without both VSS pins.

[image]

I would look for a cheap replacement CPU. They are still sold (ebay has a several of them), though shipping might be more than the CPU itself.

Comment: "though shipping might be more than the CPU itself." - You are looking at an arm and a leg, given the part will be chump change, compared to the shipping costs.

Comment: I'd have to agree with this, without those pins the CPU will never receive any valid data bytes irrespective of whether the power situation is fine. It will never be able to execute the BIOS startup code. Vss is the ground (negative connection) for the CPU.

Comment: I have figured out that my 486 CPU is fried and that means it will never work again.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the CPU pins are broken off, thereby making the CPU unusable.  The only real test would be to try a known functioning CPU.  Of course, this doesnt mean the motherboard is working, either.